# Update state for a React Object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I wanted to change the value for `app_id` to Hello World during `handleChange` using state hooks. However I am not able to update the state for app_id and didn't find a way to update the value for `app_id` before submitting the form.

To further clarify, `app_id` is a dropdown and has a `custom` option. When the custom option is selected I want the value for `app_id` to be picked from the custom text box before submitting the form. For this, I was trying to replace the previous value in `app_id` with the value of `custom_app_id` (Text Box).

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { useState , useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Button, Form  } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  const initialValues = { username:"" , email: "", password: "", account_id: "", app_id:"", custom_app_id:""};
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } =e.target;
    if (document.getElementById("app_id").value != "custom"){
      document.getElementById("custom_app_id").disabled = true;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("app_id").value === "custom"){
      document.getElementById("custom_app_id").disabled = false;
      console.log(document.getElementById("app_id").value);
      // initialValues["app_id"] =  document.getElementById("custom_app_id").value;
      setFormValues(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        ["app_id"]: "Hello World"
    }));
    }
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [id]: value });
    console.log(formValues);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors((validate(formValues)));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(formErrors)
    if(Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit){
      console.log(formValues);
    }
  }, [formErrors]);
  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    var numcheck = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if( !values.username){
      errors.username = "Username is required"
    }
    if( !values.email){
      errors.email = "Email is required"
    }
    if( !values.password){
      errors.password = "Password is required"
    }
    if(  numcheck.test(values.account_id) === false ){
      errors.account_id = "Account ID should only have numbers and cannot be empty"
    }
    if( !values.app_id){
      errors.app_id = "App ID is required"
    }
    return errors;
  };



  return (
    <div style={{  display: "block", width: 1000, padding: 30 }}>
    <h4>Self Service UI - Version 2.0</h4>
    <pre> { JSON.stringify(formValues)}</pre>
    <Container>
    <Form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" value={formValues.username} onChange={handleChange} />
        <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formErrors.username}</p>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Enter your email address:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your your email address" value={formValues.email} onChange={handleChange} />
        <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formErrors.email}</p>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Enter your password:</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" value={formValues.password} onChange={handleChange} />
        <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formErrors.password}</p>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>account_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              id="account_id"
              type="text"
              placeholder="This is typically 9 digits"
              value={formValues.account_id}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
             <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formErrors.account_id}</p>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>app_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              className="custom-select"
              id="app_id"
              value={formValues.app_id}  
              onChange={handleChange}
             >
              <option value="" hidden>This is typically 3 characters.</option>
              <option value="cs">contentserv</option>
              <option value="ew">enterworks</option>
              <option value="ep">epcc</option>
              <option value="gms">gms</option>
              <option value="iu">internal-use</option>
              <option value="is">intershop</option>
              <option value="mag">magento</option>
              <option value="oc">oracle-commerce</option>
              <option value="stb">stibo</option>
              <option value="nat">natalie</option>
              <option value="custom">Custom/Others</option>
            </Form.Control>
            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formErrors.app_id}</p>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>custom_app_id</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="This is typically 3 characters."
              id="custom_app_id"
              disabled="disabled"
              type="text"
              value={formValues.custom_app_id}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
      </Form.Group> 
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Click here to submit form
      </Button>
    </Form>
    </Container>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "I am running into issues" doesn't really describe a specific problem.  In what way does the code shown not work as expected?  Which specific operation in the code shown is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: @David agreed, however, if you are using form submit, then make put e.preventDefault() at the top to stop navigating away from the page.

Comment: @Maverick: Maybe, if that's even the issue here.  But the code shown has no form, no submit operation.  If `handleChange` is invoked when changing the value of an input and some other operation is invoked when submitting the form, `preventDefault()` isn't necessary.  And in any event, the heavy use of `document.getElementById` implies that there are *a lot* of problems in this "react" code...

Comment: @David, Yes, you are correct, I didn't notice the updated explanation. I tried the code that you have posted in my local environment and state seems to be updating perfectly and I didn't find any issue.

Comment: @Maverick - I have posted the whole code. Just I want to override the app_id previously set in the form.

Comment: Your `document.getElementById("app_id").value === "custom"` is probably the one that is not returning the correct result. Why don't you use the `value` which you are destructuring from `e.target` instead of getElement?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, I figured out a solution for this by directly assigning values to `formValues.app_id`  in `handleChange` function. Here is my change (Rest of the code is same as it is):

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } =e.target;
    if(id === "app_id" && value === "custom"){
      document.getElementById("custom_app_id").disabled = false;
    }
    if(id === "app_id" && value !== "custom"){
      document.getElementById("custom_app_id").disabled = true;
    }
    if(id === "custom_app_id" && value !== ""){
      formValues.app_id = document.getElementById("custom_app_id").value
      console.log(formValues.app_id);
    }
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [id]: value });
    console.log(formValues);
  };
```